# Specify function return type

Tags: powershell

How do I specify the return type in a powershell function?

```
function getSomeString {
    return "hello world"
}
$xyz = getSomeString()  # <--- IDE does not recognize $xyz as a string
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Before getting to the answer, I should point out that **PowerShell commands do NOT have static return types**!

In terms of I/O, commands in PowerShell are like little black boxes - you send 0 or more input objects in one end, and 0 or more outputs object are emitted at the other end - the *type(s) of which may vary*.

---

That being said, you can add a type inference hint to your function by [adding an `[OutputType]` attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_outputtypeattribute) decorator to the function's `param` block:

```
function Get-SomeString {
    [OutputType([string])]
    param()
    
    return "hello world"
}

$xyz = Get-SomeString # Tools can now infer type of `$xyz`
```

---

Again, this is a *hint*, not a guarantee - you can lie if you want to:

```
function Get-Integers
{
  [OutputType([int[]])]
  param()

  if((1..10 |Get-Random) -gt 7){
    return "lol, I'll do what I want"
  }

  return 1,2,3
}

$f = Get-Integers
```

In this case, `Get-Integers` will return a `[string]` 30% of the time, but the IDE will always act like both `$f` and `Get-Integers` resolves to an array of `[int]'s` - because that's what we told it to expect.

Comment: As a note, this is purely for tooling and doesn't constrain the function.  It can still return any type of object .

Comment: @MikeShepard yep, that's why I specifically used "type inference hint" rather than "return type". Might be worth explaining though...

Comment: Yeah, I just figured that since PowerShell's typing is somewhat unusual it was worth spelling it out.  I knew you knew the details, but some might not.

Comment: @MikeShepard For sure, I've updated the answer now, thanks for flagging it :)